# Any ad network for XNA games on the PC platform?

Tags: xna

There's a lot of press about the ad controls included on the new 7 phone, but I'm looking for candidates for the PC platform.

Comment: I would be interested to know if a framework exists for .NET. (or something that could be ported/used without a huge hassle)

Answer (score 2):

While I am not aware of any XNA specific ad controls (heck, I do now even know a single Windows based ad platform at all and Google fails me; the only one I saw is/was used in FeedDemon seems to be HTML based [The Deck](http://decknetwork.net/) and targeted at “creative, web and design professionals”, which might not intersect your audience…) I would assume that any Windows supporting platform could be used within an XNA game. However, it might involve quite a bit of work to get the ad rendered onto a D3D surface if the ad framework does not support it itself (and it might even be next to impossible). I would search for something that gives you raw text/image and a link to open as this would be the easiest way to integrate into your game.

As a side note: I have no idea how well-received an ad-supported game would be or how much revenue it could collect. The pessimist might assume that a donate PayPal button will perform better for a mid-popular game than any form of advertisement ever will…

Answer (score -4):

http:// advertising.microsoft.com/mobile-apps

> Download the free Microsoft
>   Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 7
>   for mobile applications using the XNA
>   Framework or Silverlight.

http:// www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b0f00afc-9709-4cc2-ba2c-57728db6cbd6

Comment: -1: Read the question more carefully.